# replacing newline character and comma using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, regex

I have script to fetch the address from the textbox and  want to remove all the comma and newline character in the given address .I have tried using 2 methods  but both methods are giving error .Please give some suggestion.

Sample Code:

```
<textarea rows="3" cols="33" name="inc_Address" id="inc_address" required></textarea>
```

**method1**

```
<Script>
    function tidyAddress() {
        addrArray = document.getElementById('inc_address').value.split(" ");
        var addrArray2 = addrArray.replace(/\n|\r|,/g, "");
    }
</script>
```

**method2**

```
<Script>
    function trim(str) {
        return str.replace(/\n|\r|,/g, "");
    }

    function tidyAddress() {
        addrArray = document.getElementById('inc_address').value.split(" ");
        var addrArray2 = trim(addrArray);
    }
</script>
```

> Giving error as Uncaught TypeError: addrArray.replace is not a function

Comment: var  addrArray = document.getElementById('inc_address').value.split(" ");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `replace()` method searches a string for a specified value, or a regular expression, and returns a new string where the specified values are replaced.

You are using `split()` before that and it will return an array so you are getting error.

You should try :

```
var addrString = document.getElementById('inc_address').value;
addrString.replace(/\n|\r|,/g, " ");
```

Comment: I give address as "abc cd" it giving output as "a,b,c, ,c,d"

Comment: @user092 I don't get the output as you mentioned. Please recheck

Comment: No,I have address like this "abc defg,hijk,xyz"  I want to remove comma and store back in array .

Comment: how you stored the result of addrString.replace(/\n|\r|,/g, " "); can I apply split after that? Please suggest

Comment: yes @user092 you can use as `addrString.replace(/\n|\r|,/g, " ").split(" ");` and you will get result as `["abc", "defg", "hijk", "xyz"]`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to apply string functions on array

```
 addrArray.replace(/\n|\r|,/g, ""); \\ wrong => addrArray is a array not string
```

also

```
trim(addrArray)  \\ where trim() returns string not array
```

to replace the values from array

```
var result = [];
addrArray.forEach(function(value){
    result.push( value.replace(/[\n\r\,]+/g, ' ') );
})
```

Comment: I don't want to replace textarea value but I want to store the address in array which is separated by space and all newline character and comma are removed